# I'm new to ionic, can anyone help me . I'm using ionic 1 .

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic , I want to record the last date when the app is refreshed by an user and need to show the same value in UI. The value should come as one hour back, 2 hours back and so forth ....if the app is refreshed yesterday then it should say yesterday. Even if u tell me a function then i will be good to go. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), which provides you with functions for obtaining the current timestamp - `moment.now()` - and to parse it into human-readable strings - `moment('1496239022').fromNow()`.

You can even choose the locale so the human-readable strings are properly translated - `moment.locale()`

In essence, you would save the refresh time using `moment.now()` (how or where you save it is up to you - you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you want) and then use moment.js to show the time.

Answer (score 0):

thnx alot for this solution, I solved the problem using a different method. I created variables to store current time and saved it in an array . And compared them to print time difference where in time-diff function has if-else condition to print it to be minute hour and so on. ! :) I will try ur solution now.And will let u know if it works !.Thanx again !

Comment: No problems! Be sure to accept my answer if it works!